# Как динамичеки менять ширину элементов в egui/rust при горизонтальном расположении нескольких элементов?

Tags: gui, rust

Столкнулся со странным багом при работе в библиотеке EGUI с помощью RUST. По логике программы - необходимо вывести 2 text_edit_multiline в горизонтальной плоскости. Они должны занимать все доступное пространство и растягиватся. У меня прекрасно получается создавать такие блоки по 1. В этом случае использую следующий код. Он работает как требуется, но выводит поля в вертикальной плоскости.

```
fn update(&mut self, ctx: &egui::Context, _frame: &mut eframe::Frame) {
        egui::CentralPanel::default().show(ctx, |ui| {
            ui.heading("My egui Application");
            ui.vertical_centered_justified(|ui| {
                
                    let field1_label = ui.label("Write your yaml here");
                    ui.text_edit_multiline(&mut self.field1)
                        .labelled_by(field1_label.id);
                    let field1_label = ui.label("Write your yaml here");
                    ui.text_edit_multiline(&mut self.field1)
                        .labelled_by(field1_label.id);
                
            });

        });
    }
```

[image: Общий вид gui в таком случае;]

Если же я пытаюсь разместить элементы горизонтально - адаптивность теряется.
В этом случае использую следующий код:

```
fn update(&mut self, ctx: &egui::Context, _frame: &mut eframe::Frame) {
        egui::CentralPanel::default().show(ctx, |ui| {
            ui.heading("My egui Application");
            ui.vertical_centered_justified(|ui| {
                    ui.horizontal(|ui| {
                        let field1_label = ui.label("Write your yaml here");
                        ui.text_edit_multiline(&mut self.field1)
                            .labelled_by(field1_label.id);
                        let field1_label = ui.label("Write your yaml here");
                        ui.text_edit_multiline(&mut self.field1)
                            .labelled_by(field1_label.id);
                    });
                    
                
            });

        });
```

И получаю такое отображение:[image]

кто-то может подсказать что я делаю неправильно? В идеале хотелось бы видеть разбиение ширины или высоты на число элементов в горизонтали/вертикали. В примерах подобного не нашел.